# how to scroll a position:absolute with the bowser scroll?

Tags: html, css

I have three div-layers. The first layer is the background with a designated height. the second layer is a transparent div for the content-class.In the third layer is the content. I want to remove the scroll of .content class and I want to scroll the text with the browser scroll. How can I do it?

```css
.container{
  background-color:black;
  height:400px;
  wdith:100%;
}   
.backtransparent{
  background-color: gray;
  width:250px;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}   
.content{
  width:200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:white;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:auto;
  height:400px;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="backtransparent">
    <div class="content">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia maxime facere quae cumque perferendis cum atque quia repellendus rerum eaque quod quibusdam incidunt blanditiis possimus temporibus reiciendis deserunt sequi eveniet necessitatibus maiores quas assumenda voluptate qui odio laboriosam totam repudiandae? Doloremque dignissimos voluptatibus eveniet rem quasi minus ex cumque esse culpa cupiditate cum architecto! Facilis deleniti unde suscipit minima obcaecati vero ea soluta odddio cupiditate placeat vitae nesciunt quis alias dolorum nemo sint facere. Deleniti itaque incidunt eligendi qui nemo corporis ducimus beatae consequatur...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the full example: https://jsfiddle.net/yrp4pmmc/2/

Comment: If I get it right, you can't, unless your browser window has height less than `400px` it won't show the scroll bars.

Comment: @JordiNebot The height is predefined.I want to scroll only the text with the browser scroll (not with a separately scrol like this way).

Comment: You can't get it with browser scroll if your container's height needs to be fixed at 400px and your window is higher, but @sTx's answer seems a pretty good aprox...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something [like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/yrp4pmmc/5/)

```
.container{
background-color: black;
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
}
.content{
width: 240px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: white;
left: 0;
right: 0;
border-left: 20px solid grey;
border-right: 20px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: Good to remove the useless element, and also you don't need the left and right CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/yrp4pmmc/6/

Comment: yeah, I've forgot them there, no need for left or right because I've removed the absolute positioning

Answer (score 2):

Unless I've misunderstood your question, all you have to do is remove your absolute positioning and make the parent `div` 100% height.

Removing the specified height on the divs ensures they take up the size of the content, as divs by default do. Then when you limit the width of the .content element and remove its ability to scroll, .container must take up the entire height of its child elements.

```
.container{
   background-color:black;
   height: 100%;
   width:100%;
}

.backtransparent{
  background-color: gray;
  width:250px;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content{
  width:200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:white;
  overflow:auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/yrp4pmmc/3/

Comment: So the `height: 400px` of the `.container` was totally arbitrary?

Comment: Seems that way. I may have misunderstood, but to get the "browser scroll" back, the elements have to wrap their children and not have a specific height applied.